# Función `all` de Matlab en Julia

Tags: matlab, julia

Buenas:

¿Existe un equivalente en Julia a [la función `all` de Matlab](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.html)?

¡Gracias!

Comment: Pero has buscado en internet antes de preguntar? http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/collections/?highlight=all#Base.all

Comment: @TomFenech Si lo he hecho ..

Answer (score 2):

Me han contestado en el foro de Julia (varios días después). También se llama `all` pero la sintaxis es distinta, en el caso de un vector en Matlab es `all(A)` y en Julia `all(i->(i!=0),A)`

Comment: Bueno, técnicamente es la respuesta a la pregunta :) ¿Podrías añadir el enlace al mensaje de la lista de correo correspondiente?

Comment: A que lista de correos te refieres @astrojuanlu?

Comment: Al foro de Julia donde te dieron la respuesta